# crypt() php function add VOF to end of crypted password

Tags: php, hash, passwords, crypt

I'm trying to compare two crypted passwords to validate a login form by using

```
if (crypt($_POST["password"], $user["password"]) == $user["password"])
```

but it never matches, so I printed the contents of both  $user["password"] and crypt($_POST["password"], $user["password"]) to the console and got this:

```
$user["password"] = $1$M/IEG2Xm$nMA2j1eTaXIXy6jvRe
crypt($_POST["password"], $user["password"]) = $1$M/IEG2Xm$nMA2j1eTaXIXy6jvReVOF.
```

What is that "VOF." at the end of it? How do I get rid of that?
Thanks!

Comment: It's just the password hash. Also, you should use the `password_hash` function with `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`.

Comment: But why doesn't it appear on the other crypted password as well?

Comment: Are you sure that your database isn't truncating the `VOF.` off the end of it?

Comment: OMG! that was it....sorry, and thanks!!